# Caret Package in R

Tags: machine-learning, caret

I'm starting with the `caret` package in `R` and I was wondering when we use train()
if all the work was done by the function?

I read that feature selection is already done for multiple algorithms, the parameters are found with a grid search but for imbalance dataset I don't know if
there is an automatic method? (there is a parameter "weight", and a few function like SMOTE but not sure it is tuned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `train` does most of the work. This is mainly because you need to have e.g. certain preprocessing (those that depends on data) to be done within your partitioning/resampling, as you otherwise will overfit those as well. `train` tries to give you a good estimate of what your model performance on unseen data is going to be. Be sure to use some repeated cross validation or similar (with sufficient partitions and repeats). After this, `train` automatically uses the best found configuration (e.g. parameter grid) to train a final model using all training data you provided. This model is the one that gets returned - so all you usually need to do is use this one model and use obtained performance metrics from evaluating it before to see its expected performance.

For your other questions:

- The `weight` parameter is handed to those underlying methods that can handle it. So not all methods will be able to use it.
- For sampling within caret `train`: you are most likely referring to the `sampling` parameter in `train`, which is available in newer versions of caret (see [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/sampling.html#resampling) for more details on how to use it and some examples).

Comment: So in case of imbalance dataset for example 2000 for class c1 , 120 class c2 and 70 class c3 if the algorithm in train() has access to "weight" it will automatically find the best weight combination for each class ?

Comment: No, you would need to specify the weights you want yourself, and those will depend on the underlying model.